# Thumbnail not shown when posting url of website with youtube embedded video

Tags: php, html, facebook, video, youtube

I am posting url of website on Facebook. That website has a YouTube video embedded in it.
 Url of website is :

```
 [http://www.successb.com/videos/Full_College_Masti.html][1]
```

When posting url of website on Facebook than thumbnail is not shown. Just simple url is shown.

I don't have any idea why thumbnail is not shown or what I have to do so that thumbnail is shown when I post url of website to my Facebook group.

Any help in this issue is most welcome.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.successb.com%2Fvideos%2FFull_College_Masti.html – if you want a specific thumbnail image to be shown, then you have to specify that via the og meta tags within the HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Comment posted by CBroe worked.

For meta code you can refer to

http://ogp.me/